# PHP_CodeSniffer missing Zend standards?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pear, phpcodesniffer

I'm trying to use PHP_CodeSniffer to sniff the problems in a php file according to the zend coding standards.
The problem is some of the basic rules are not detected, for example

```
String Literals
$a = "Example String";
should give a warning because the standard is
$a = 'Example String';
```

Am I missing something, is this not part of the code standard ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of the Zend Coding Standard according to the [respective pages in the ZF Reference Guide](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html). However, that does not necessarily mean all these rules have been included in [phpcs](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected). They are unrelated projects. If you look at the [ruleset defined for ZF in phpcs](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/packages/PHP_CodeSniffer/trunk/CodeSniffer/Standards/Zend/ruleset.xml?view=markup), you will see this notice right on top:

> A coding standard based on an early Zend Framework coding standard. Note that this standard is out of date.

Judging by a [comment by Thomas Weidner](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/ZF+Coding+Standards+%28RC%29?focusedCommentId=15565699#comment-15565699) in the [Wiki for ZF Coding Standards](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/ZF+Coding+Standards+%28RC%29), there is currently no up-to-date PHPCS ruleset available:

> My code sniffer implementation was not finished but it has also not been accepted by Zend. Several rules did not conform, were not checked, or were too strict. I had to delete it from Incubator. You can find the latest version by looking into SVN (
>
> The CS files delivered with PHPCS do not conform any ZF standard.
>
> I was said that Zend will not integrate a own CS testbed as it will use the new Pear2 standard as soon as it's available. This is the reason why I did not do any additional work since last year.
>
> So the actual state is that there is no official CS testbed available.